# engine initialization failed for the first time in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-dependencies, flutter-test, dart-pub

I am using [flutter file view](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_file_view) package to view document files but for the first it shows engine initialization failed and after restart app it work fine can someone help plzdart

```
          FileView(controller: widget.controller),
```

widdget.controller is the path of file

Comment: Please share the code segment for better understanding of your problem statement

Comment: edited. check out this package because its only one line of code and i follow this package step by step. problem is that when open app for first time it show engine initialization failed and when restart app then it work fine

Comment: Please share your main.dart for better understanding